# Why can't Python infer that my class follows the Sequence protocol?

Tags: python, duck-typing

I would expect that if I write a class that implements all methods needed for a `Sequence` as per https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/collections.abc.html, that Python would use duck-typing to know that an instance of it is a Sequence, but I find that is not the case:

```py
from collections.abc import Sequence

class MySequence:
    def __getitem__(self, ix):
        pass
    
    def __iter__(self):
        pass
    
    def __len__(self):
        pass
    
    def __contains__(self, val):
        pass
    
    def __reversed__(self):
        pass
    
    def count(self, val):
        pass
    
    def index(self, val):
        pass

seq = MySequence()
print(isinstance(seq, Sequence))
```

This prints False instead of True. Why?

Comment: `def __getitem__(self):` isn't compatible with `Sequence` (or even usable?). See [`object.__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)

Comment: I didn't think that the duck-typing mechansim actually checks the arguments of the function. Does it? Is that what you're getting at? @Brian61354270

Comment: For avoidance of doubt, I'll update my snippet so that all the function signatures take the right  number of arguments (and I've verified that the outcome is still the same).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No duck-typing here. If you're not inheriting from the `Sequence` abc at all, then you'll need to register your class:

```
Sequence.register(MySequence)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) point 3) concerning duck-typing:

> Some simple interfaces are directly recognizable by the presence of the required methods
>
> ...
>
> Complex interfaces do not support this last technique because an interface is more than just the presence of method names. Interfaces specify semantics and relationships between methods that cannot be inferred solely from the presence of specific method names. For example, knowing that a class supplies `__getitem__`, `__len__`, and `__iter__` is insufficient for distinguishing a `Sequence` from a `Mapping`.

Comment: Another docs link you can reference: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence. _"The collections.abc.Sequence abstract base class defines a much richer interface ... Types that implement this expanded interface can be registered explicitly using register()."_

Comment: Okay, so I suppose this explanation still leaves room for `isinstance(seq, Container)` to return True (which it does), right? Because maybe `Container` is not  a "complex interface".

Comment: Right. It should be instance of `collections.abc.Iterable` without needing registration too.

Comment: To be clear, did you just mean to write `abc.Container`? Not sure where `abc.Iterable` came from.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare I think wim was just offering an example of another ABC that doesn't require registration. In fact, any ABC in [this table](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) that's marked with a `[1]` footnote doesn't require explicit registration.